# Change MAC Address on Android 10

Tags: mac-address

I am running a Nokia 8.1 with Android 10. Now, I'd really like to change my MAC Address, though no shell commands I've found work for me. Now, I would use the randomised Mac Feature, that only gives me one random Mac per network though, which is apparently not changeable.

Now, for several reasons, I'm really not into rooting my personal main phone, so is there any way I can change my Mac without root access?

If it was needed, I'd even consider a system reset.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to change your tablet MAC this awnser wont help you, but if you want to keep changing your random MAC you can look here https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/225839/android-10-and-11-get-new-random-mac-for-same-ssid-without-factory-reset